# How I can manage different layout in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How I can have a special layout in Ruby On Rails 4? For example, I want to call the `show` method from the backend and front end. The problem is that I need to identify when to call each layout, for example, when calling the URL `domain.com/admin/people/1` I want to call backend layout, but when I call the URL `domain.com/people/1`, I want to call the layout of the front end.

Comment: Do you have separate controllers for People and AdminPeople?

Comment: no, I'm using one controller for everything. A good practice is that I separate the logic backend and frontend? (People and AdminPeople)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create your layout in the layouts directory, ie at `layouts/admin.html.erb`

Route to separate controllers:

```
class AdminPeopleController 

   def show
       #do things
      render layout: 'admin'
   end
end

class PeopleController
  def show
       #do things
      render #default
   end
end
```

And add in your routes file:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :people, controller: :admin_people
end

resources :people, controller: :people
```